# Display Site Collection Web Analytics Report from multiple site collections on a page

Tags: site-collection, export, reports

I have a requirement to display the Site Collection Web Analytics reports for several site collections in one place. How can I do this, as it seems SharePoint doesn't allow for much in the way of customization of this report and how it is presented?